# Pass a value from one page to another use button or link and code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net, C#, I actually want 3 conditions on a particular click to delete a record:
1. Ask for confirmation
2. Redirect to another page
3. Pass the id of the record to be deleted internally(not present in any text field or anything) to the next page whose record has to be deleted

If i use a link i an fulfill the 2nd and 3rd condition by using a query string

but if i use a button, then i can fulfill the 1st and 2nd condition.

and in the onclick i redirect it to the next page.

I tried with postback url also, it gives the value 0.

Can anybody tell me what should i use and how so that all the 3 conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: What problem are you having with _"1st condition - Ask for confirmation"_ when using a `link` ?

Comment: i mean that when i use a link. i can be redirected to another page and pass a value also using the query string, But  how can i ask for a confirmation from the user like "Are you sure if you want to delete or not?". before deleting the record?

Comment: You can do that with some javascript.  If the user does not 'confirm' the link does not postback.  How you are you handling the confirmation in the button scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the answer to this. i simple used this in the onclick event of the button:

string redirect = string.Format("~/Admin-DeleteEmployee.aspx?Id=" + id + "");
Response.Redirect(redirect);

and i can ask for confirmation also and redirect the page along with the value. So all the three conditions are satisfied. Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If the ID of the record is passed in the ID of the button, you can use something like this when it is clicked

```
protected void ButtonCliked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string buttonID = "";
    if (sender is Button)
    {
        buttonID = ((Button)sender).ClientID;

        string url = "RedirectUrl.aspx?buttonID=" + buttonID;
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried using this:
            string redirect = string.Format("~/Admin-DeleteEmployee.aspx?Id=", +id);
            Response.Redirect(redirect);... but it passes only the string ~/Admin-DeleteEmployee.aspx?Id=", the actual value of ID does not go along to the next page